# React.js load component only once to work with state

Tags: reactjs

I have the following part of code:

```js
<div>
  {!store.getState().obj.is_fetching ? <Content /> : <LoremIpsum p={10} /> }
</div>
```

The above is basically that this waits for an ajax request that adds `is_fetching = false` when its complete to the Redux state store, so in its ajax complete it will show the main content, `<Content />`, but until the complete, it shows `<LoremIpsum p={10} />`.

What the `<LoremIpsum p={10} />` component does is basically it generates a series of random paragraphs.

But now the implementation has a problem. Since the Redux store.getState() is fired continuously for tens of times until its bool change, the page shows tens of the random paragraphs in a couple of seconds.

This is not a desired result, but I wanted to implement only once show a single randomly-generated paragraphs on the page while the ajax wait.

How can I work around the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use componentDidMount Here;

```
state = { isLoading: !store.getState().obj.is_fetching }

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isLoading: !store.getState().obj.is_fetching })
}

render() {
    return(
        this.state.isLoading ? <Content /> :  <LoremIpsum p={10} />
    )
}
```

with Hooks;

```
  var is_fetching = !store.getState().obj.is_fetching;
  const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(is_fetching);

  // It will be executed before rendering

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setIsLoading(is_fetching), 1000)
  }, []);

  // [] means like componentDidMount

  return isLoading ? <LoremIpsum p={10} /> : <div>Your content</div>;
```